# Return value of a switch is always 0

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing a project for school and I'm trying to calculate the fuel consumption of a car over a certain distance but the switch always returns 0. I tried different things but none of them seem to work.

```
    public Double DetermineFuelConsumption (String Car, Double Kilometers)
    {
        Double FuelConsumption = 0;

        switch (Car)
        {
            // (14 / 100) ---> Liters per 100 Kilometers
            case "LaFerrari":
                FuelConsumption = (14 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Nissan GT-R Nismo":
                FuelConsumption = (12 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Pagani Huayra":
                FuelConsumption = (18 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "McLaren P1":
                FuelConsumption = (8 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Lamborghini Aventador":
                FuelConsumption = (16 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Smart":
                FuelConsumption = (4 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Porsche 911":
                FuelConsumption = (9 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
            case "Audi R8":
                FuelConsumption = (15 / 100) * Kilometers;
                break;
        }
        return FuelConsumption;
    }
```

Comment: have you checked by debugging what's inside car variable?

Comment: Show an example call that is returning zero.

Comment: search for integer division

Comment: I would avoid switching on a string. Try an enum instead.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Inside the car variable is the name of the car that the user has to choose from a combobox. That bit works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of those numbers that you are dividing by 100 will yield 0.

This is integer division: the result of an integer divided by an integer is always an integer. You need to specify that your numbers are floating point types:

```
public Double DetermineFuelConsumption (String Car, Double Kilometers)
{
    Double FuelConsumption = 0;

    switch (Car)
    {
        // (14 / 100) ---> Liters per 100 Kilometers
        case "LaFerrari":
            FuelConsumption = (14d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Nissan GT-R Nismo":
            FuelConsumption = (12d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Pagani Huayra":
            FuelConsumption = (18d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "McLaren P1":
            FuelConsumption = (8d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Lamborghini Aventador":
            FuelConsumption = (16d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Smart":
            FuelConsumption = (4d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Porsche 911":
            FuelConsumption = (9d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
        case "Audi R8":
            FuelConsumption = (15d / 100d) * Kilometers;
            break;
    }
    return FuelConsumption;
}
```

Here, the `d` suffix specifies that those numbers are doubles, not integers.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
FuelConsumption = (14d / 100d) * Kilometers;
```

Comment: (On all expressions where a division is carried out, since `16 / 100` is an integer divions so this will give `0` and not `0.16f`.)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to divide 2 integers (a / b), which in case **a < b** will be a fraction which **0.some-number** which in turn will be **rounded to int**, that means 0. Then multiply 0 * Kilometers, well.. you see the picture.

Change it to `(14 / 100d)` instead.